# SQL - Select distinct on two column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, duplicates, distinct

I have this table 'words' with more information:

```
+---------+------------+-----------
| ID      |ID_CATEGORY | ID_THEME |
+---------+------------+-----------
| 1       |      1     |     1
| 2       |      1     |     1
| 3       |      1     |     1
| 4       |      1     |     2
| 5       |      1     |     2
| 6       |      1     |     2
| 7       |      2     |     3
| 8       |      2     |     3
| 9       |      2     |     3
| 10      |      2     |     4
| 11      |      2     |     4
| 12      |      3     |     5
| 13      |      3     |     5
| 14      |      3     |     6
| 15      |      3     |     6
| 16      |      3     |     6
```

And this query that gives to me 3 random ids from different categories, but not from  different themes too:

```
SELECT Id
FROM words
GROUP BY Id_Category, Id_Theme
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3
```

What I want as result is:

```
+---------+------------+-----------
| ID      |ID_CATEGORY | ID_THEME |
+---------+------------+-----------
| 2       |      1     |     1
| 7       |      2     |     3
| 14      |      3     |     6
```

That is, repeat no category or theme.

Comment: Try to use GROUP BY like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/54430/2717958

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
"If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function." Your id column doesn't follow this.

Comment: in first row -->  2 1 1 or 1 1 1 .... @ismaestro

Comment: Try this `select distinct id,id_cat,id_theme from (
select id,id_cat,id_theme,id_cat+id_theme tc from words)y
limit 3 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `GROUP BY` you cannot include in the select list a column which is not being ordered. So, in your query it's impossible to inlcude `Id` in the select list.

So you need to do something a bit more complex:

```
SELECT Id_Category, Id_Theme,
    (SELECT Id FROM Words W 
      WHERE W.Id_Category = G.Id_Category AND W.Id_Theme = G.Id_Theme
      ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
    ) Id
FROM Words G
GROUP BY Id_Category, Id_Theme
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3
```

NOTE: the query groups by the required columns, and the subselect is used to take a random `Id` from all the possible `Id`s in the group. Then main query is filtered to take three random rows.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. No error appears just a blank web page, maybe a syntax problem?

Comment: do you have a db manager, like pgAdmin, to run the query and see the results without the web app in the middle?

Comment: everything works fine with the sql query. There was another problem with PHP... ;)